# How to get the records created in last 5 minutes within a 4m records table?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL table `activity_logs` which saves all API calls made by client apps since the very beginning, the app has been launched a couple of years, and this table now has 4.5 million records.

It worths to notice that each record will have an incremental ID, and also the `created_at` field won't be updated after the record is created, so the values of `created_at` is basically incremental in the same way as `id` field.

- `id` is the primary key
- `created_at` is not indexed

I noticed a performance issue today when I need to query the records created in last 5 minutes, I did something simple like `where("created_at", ">=", now()->subMinutes(5))` in my PHP code, and shortly notice this query had searched all 4.5 million records and was terribly slow. However, it makes sense because database engine doesn't know that `created_at` is always incremental in my case.

I paused before blindly adding an index to `created_at` to fix it, the value of `created_at` is so diverse so adding an index to it doesn't sound to be right. I ended up with two separate queries.

- `SELECT id FROM activity_logs WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
- `SELECT * FROM activity_logs WHERE id > [Query Result]`

It works well, but I am wondering what's the **standard** way to deal with this issue, as I believe it is a very common issue. I am in love with PHP/Laravel and ORM and didn't follow up on SQL topics too much, and would like to see your insights.

Comment: You have it right with the index on `created_at`.  If it's not indexed already it will make a huge difference.  Since API call log data is not transactional, it's not a fantastic fit for relational databases in the first place.  A logging mechanism would probably be a better fit for that kind of data.  That being said, 4.5M records is not much for mysql and an index should make the problem disappear.

Comment: I've done a quick check on this and I am not sure if it's possible in MySQL, but the way I deal with log tables in SQL Server is to make the created date the clustering index, as typically this is the main basis of any query on a log table, and they satisfy 3 of the 4 requirements for a clustering key (static, narrow, ever increasing). What the date doesn't satisfy is the 4th criterion of being unique, so you either need to add further columns to make it unique, or use a DMBS that allows a non-unique clustering key. (cont)

Comment: This is where I am not sure with MySQL as it is not my area of expertise. I don't think you can have a non-unique clustered index in MySQL as the clustered index must be the primary key, but If you could combine other columns in the primary key to guarantee uniqueness in each row, you could drop your id column and cluster on datetime and whatever other columns are needed to be unique. If you can't guarantee uniqueness using other columns, then I think a non-clustered index is the best you will do

Comment: @GarethD Thanks, I will take a look at clustering index, sounds like something cool.

Answer (score 1):

Add `INDEX(created_at)`,  then use

```
WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
ORDER BY created_at, id
```

More details:

- I assume (hope) that you have `ENGINE=InnoDB` on that table
- If you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then it is clustered on `id` and MySQL *cannot* provide another cluster index.
- The secondary index suggested above has `id` silently tacked on the end.  (That is also how it finds the row.)
- The code I suggest will be fast.
- MySQL has no `CLUSTERED` keyword.  The PK *is* clustered and *is* Unique and *is* an index.  (MySQL is 'lean an mean'; it does not have as many bells and whistles as other vendors *because* they aren't worth the effort to implement and maintain.)
- A similar trick (but not really necessary here) is

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY(created_at, id),  -- To get the clustering you desire
    INDEX(id)    -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
  ```

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your answer. I agree and I don't want to add `created_at` into the primary key (i.e. the only clustered index). I kind of know that adding index to `created_at` field will improve the query performance, but adding index to 4 million records will take some time, because most of time I never add indexes to timestamps while creating a new table. I am curious if this is the common solution for issues like this, and if so why popular frameworks like Laravel, Ruby on Rails didn't put indexes there by default.

Comment: My impression is that most of the hundred-or-so frameworks are designed for beginners' datasets.  Few, if any, worry about million-row issues.  And, once the framework becomes popular, fixing poor indexes and other design issues becomes next to impossible.  I've been battling with WP for years to get some indexes improved.